# Android: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 9, size is 9

Tags: android, if-statement, int, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm having a problem with my following code:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {
        int row = position +1;
        int listLength = data.size();
        HashMap<String,String> nextRow = data.get(position+1);
        if (row < listLength ) {
            nextRow.put("greyedOut","false");
        } else {
            System.out.println("HATSIKIDEE!!");
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        System.out.println(row);
        System.out.println(listLength);
    }
});
```

This code is placed in my `Adapter` and adjusts the `ListView`, it works for every row but crashes when selecting the last row returning the following error: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 9, size is 9`

What I don't understand is that the output of the System.out.println() is according to if statement:

```
    1 of 9
    2 of 9
    3 of 9
    4 of 9
    5 of 9
    6 of 9
    7 of 9
    8 of 9

At 9 of 9 it crashes.
Please help me how to solve this error.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this then:

```
HashMap<String,String> nextRow = null;
if (position + 1 < listLength)
{
    nextRow = data.get(position+1); 
}
if (nextRow != null)
{
    //whatever it is you are trying to achieve by detecting the next row
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HashMap<String,String> nextRow = data.get(position);
```

instead of

```
HashMap<String,String> nextRow = data.get(position+1);
```

index always starts from `0` not from `1`

then you will get

```
0 of 9
1 of 9
2 of 9
3 of 9
4 of 9
5 of 9
6 of 9
7 of 9
8 of 9
```

**TOTAL = 9**

Comment: the nextRow makes the row below it visual and active that is the whole meaning of this statement. But because there is no next row below the last row I want it to stop performing that change. That is why I compare it to the size of the array.

Comment: try this  `int row = position;` instead of  `int row = position +1;`

Comment: data.get(9) will cause a IndexOutOfBoundsException - every time. And you will notice that data.get(8) is your last element in the array.

Have you at least tried our idea (it's not usual for 2 people with exactly the same idea at the same time to be completely wrong)? What happened?

Comment: Already tried this same result. position 9 tries to make the next row active and there is no next row.

Answer (score 1):

```
int row = position + 1;
int listLength = data.size();
HashMap<String,String> nextRow = null;
if(row < listLength)
{
   nextRow = data.get(row);
}
if(nextRow != null)
{
   nextRow.put("greyedOut","false");
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
else 
{
   System.out.println("HATSIKIDEE!!");
}    
System.out.println(row);
System.out.println(listLength);
```

Comment: Sorry Kai I just tried your code and it still gives the same result. Error the moment I touch the last row.

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't think that's possible if you change the full body of your method to my code.

Comment: Is "HATSIKIDEE!!" ever printed?

Comment: thanks for your answer combined with the answer of Quitin Balsdon I got it to work.

Comment: I don't see any difference between our answers. What didn't work in my code?

Comment: I don't know but It still gave me the same error clicking on the last error. But when I read yours it does not differ in function from that of Quitin. Weird

Answer (score 0):

Java uses Zero based indexing - meaning that there will be something at position 0. This means that in any list there are 0 - (n-1) items in a list.

You need to change

```
HashMap<String,String> nextRow = data.get(position+1);
```

to 
   `HashMap<String,String> nextRow = data.get(position);`

so that the maximum INDEX you go to is 8, which is the 9th element in your list.
Your array looks like this:
[0] - 1st element
[1] - 2nd element
.... and so on.

Comment: Please see my comment on the answer above.